# Kotlin - how to get annotation attribute value

Tags: annotations, kotlin

say, i have one Kotlin class with annotations:

```
@Entity @Table(name="user") data class User (val id:Long, val name:String)
```

How can i get the value of name attribute from @Table annotation?

```
fun <T> tableName(c: KClass<T>):String {
    // i can get the @Table annotation like this:
    val t = c.annotations.find { it.annotationClass == Table::class }
    // but how can i get the value of "name" attribute from t?
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can simply:

```
val table = c.annotations.find { it is Table } as? Table
println(table?.name)
```

Note, I used the `is` operator since the annotation has `RUNTIME` retention and therefore it is an actual instance of the `Table` annotation within the collection.  But the following works for any annotation:

```
val table = c.annotations.find { it.annotationClass == Table::class } as? Table
```

Comment: `find` is equivalent of `firstOrNull`, not `first`

Comment: yep, in my mind it was backwards temporarily, just simplified the answer not worrying about it.